# Getting "None" for BS4 web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to create a code that will get the price of bitcoin
For some reason running this code will result in the output of None, however I would like the output of the current bitcoin price, how do I fix this?

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+price'
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        text = soup.find('span', {'class':'vpclqee'})
        print(text)
```

Comment: first you should display r.text to see if you get what you expected. Google could send warning for bots/spamers/hackers,  or captcha, or it can send different HTML for different browsers and devices or when browser can't use JavaScript - and `requests` send header `User-Agent` like `Python/3.x Requests/2.x` instead of `Mozilla/5.0`, and `requests`/`Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript (so it may get different HTML then real web browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no restriction on using Google's Bitcoin price, some other sites have easier access to this value, like CoinMarketCap:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"priceValue"})

for elem in text:
    print(elem.get_text())
```

But note that this is not suitable for any real-time updating as I believe it updates much too slowly.

Output:

```
$39,878.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an unnecessary `v` try to write:

```
text = soup.find('span', {'class':'pclqee'})
```

insteadof:

```
text = soup.find('span', {'class':'vpclqee'})
```

[image]